# Is 90 day visa limit applicable for the spouse of EU citizen?

Tags: visa-extensions, spouses

I will be travelling to Europe next year on a Greek passport and staying past the 90 day limit imposed on non European citizens. Will my wife be restricted to the 90 day limit or can she stay longer as we will be travelling together. My wife is Greek of heritage but born in Australia.

Answer (score 5):

If are an EU citizen, your spouse has right to reside with you. 90 days rule doesn't apply here.

Details: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/family-residence-rights/index_en.htm

Carry proof of marriage such as marriage certificate to prove the same.

Comment: The 90/180 rule will definitely apply here. What happens however is that the spouse is eligible to request a residence card to extend their stay. they can't stay more than 90 days without taking additional action.

Comment: @meego The 90/180 rule cannot apply to EU citizens and their accompanying or joining family members because the rule does not exist for them. No "overstay" (nor penalties related to that) can happen as they have a *right* of residence. Registration requirements exist for continuous stays exceeding three months in **one, single country**, but failure to register does not abrogate one's right (but administrative fines or other penalties or inconveniences may apply).

Comment: thankyou all for your feedback

Comment: @meego the Schengen Borders Code, for example, excludes people who benefit from free movement, including third-country family members, from the definition of "third-country national," so there is no legal basis for applying the Schengen 90-day limit to a third-country national who is traveling with an EU-citizen spouse.

Comment: This answer would be improved with a quote from the link supporting your assertion. I may be silly but I can’t find the information you are referring to?